# Text Classification with BERT. Reddit posts. Accuracy is constant

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, bert-language-model

**I'm trying to clasify author age group ('under 21','young adult', 'adult)**. I'm working on this example: https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/text/blob/master/docs/tutorials/classify_text_with_bert.ipynb#scrollTo=KiC1mzAnBR5Y.

**I have provided my train, test and validation data:**

- training:  31738 files belonging to 3 classes.
- validation: 3968 files belonging to 3 classes.
- test: 3966 files belonging to 3 classes.

**I have changed**:

- net = tf.keras.layers.Dense(**3**, activation=None,
  name='classifier')(net)
- classifier_model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
  metrics=['accuracy'])

**I have tried:**

- changing dropout rate
- changing batch size
- changing lerning rate
- different model (talking-heads_base)
- different optimizer (adam/adamw)
- different loss function(mae)
- addding activation function('relu')

**

### The accuracy is always near 0.3333 while loss function is decreasing

** as you can see in chart:.
[validation loss/test loss/accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etJ8w.png)

Comment: This may be appropriate for the stack - CrossValidated.

Comment: Additionally, 1/3 with three classes is essentially random. Perhaps the data does not correlate with target.

Comment: that was it, thank you :)